# I want to move the nav-item Sign up to right, I have tried ml-auto and justify-content-end yet it isn't moving

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

Tried to move the nav-item "Sign Up" to right by ml-auto and justify-content-end using Bootstrap 4 yet it isn't moving.

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-danger">
    <div class="container">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-end" id="navbarSupportedContent">
            <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Sign Up</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Just remove the `mr-auto` from both `navbar-nav`. `justify-content-end` alone will work.

Answer (score 0):

Removing mr-auto form the Sign Up navbar seems to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove "mr-auto" class from ul tag, and add below css.

```css
.navbar-nav.rightSide {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-danger">
  <div class="container">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
   </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-end" id="navbarSupportedContent">
      <ul class="navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="navbar-nav rightSide">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Sign Up</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: You can vote up my answer and also mark it as a perfect one if you are satisfied. Thanks.